# Prevent aptitude from Removing

Tags: aptitude

Is there any way of forcing Aptitude to not accept solutions using Removes?
I tried various values of `Aptitude::ProblemResolver::RemoveScore` and cannot seem to make it work.

Comment: I tried setting `Aptitude::ProblemResolver::Remove-Level` to a very big value and this at least seems likely to work as intended.